# Foundation 6 Button Group Expanded Not Working

Tags: zurb-foundation-6, buttongroup

I am using Foundation 6 Zurb Template with flexbox enabled and the expanded feature of the button group is not working.

When I add the expanded class the last button will not fill the last space and drops to the next line on the left side. The text is no longer inline and the width of the buttons are not the same.

```
<div class="expanded button-group">
  <a class="button">Expanded</a>
  <a class="button">Button</a>
  <a class="button">Group</a>
</div>
```

Any idea what could be wrong? Tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with foundation `6.2.1`, which version you are using?

see the CodePen example. http://codepen.io/shoaibik/pen/VaJbvj

Comment: Thanks Shoaib, if I put the exact code in my build it doesn't work. I believe I am using 6.2.1 (downloaded via CLI 3 weeks ago). 
The bower.json file has this code though:
 "dependencies": {
    "foundation-sites": "~6.2.0",
    "motion-ui": "~1.2.2"
  },.

Do you know if I can update the Foundation 6 Zurb Template version via the CLI? If so, any idea how? Tnx!

Comment: change `foundation-sites": "~6.2.0"` to `foundation-sites": "~6.2.1"` and run `bower update` and check again if that works.

Comment: Not sure if it actually updated anything, and no change with button group expanded issue. Someone else said that the '~' before 6.2.0 means that it automatically updates to latest version.

bower cached        https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites.git#6.2.1
bower validate      6.2.1 against https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites.git#~6.2.1
bower cached        https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.4
bower validate      2.2.4 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#~2.2.0

bower install       foundation-sites#6.2.1